# Why Google Style Guide recommend local variables for shell scripts but does not use it in examples?

Tags: bash, shell, google-style-guide

Google Style Guide says to always use `local` variables and put everything into `function`.

On the other hand [sample](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Loops#Loops) `for` loop is provided:

```
for dir in ${dirs_to_cleanup}; do
  ...
done
```

Why there is no convention to always declare loop variable as local just before loop? Or maybe the following is the way how loops inside functions should be written to comply with the style guide?

```
local dir
for dir in ${dirs_to_cleanup}; do
  ...
done
```

Comment: Style-guides are just that 'guides' (not decrees, mandates, proclamations, etc..) By declaring variables `local` to a scope you avoid name-collisions with variables of the same name elsewhere. Does that matter in a 20 line script, probably not. So they are more recommendations

Comment: `local` only makes sense in a function. What makes you think that the snippet you show is in a function?

Comment: And if the snippet were in a function, you might declare `local dir` at the top of that function, outside the "scope" of the sample.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin my question is rather about long scripts in enterprise environment where consistency and style matters. Still, I see people declaring a lot of local variables in functions, but for some reason declaring `local` for loop variable is pretty uncommon in my environment, in the samples available on the internet and even in the style guide itself. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @GemTaylor agreed, this is just small snippet where functions are not required, so local indeed wouldn't make sense